# Debugging Custom JMeter Plugin using IntelliJ Idea

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have created a custom JMeter java code which I load as an external jar in the Apache JMeter classpath. I need to use '[WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch][1]" .  The custom APIs are called in the JSR223 Preprocessor. All works fine. I am using IntelliJ idea. As an ultimate goal we will be having a custom plugin for our application.

So I want to run the JMeter script in debug mode. I want to debug our code real time and step into the plugin source code. Good to have goal is to also step into JMeter source code too.

Any help or guideline in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't different from any other Java application

1. Open your [Idea Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) and look for `Remote JVM Debug` section
2. Choose your JDK

   [image]

   Idea will generate the command-line for JVM
3. Launch JMeter using command-line from step 2 i.e.:

   ```
   java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
   ```
4. Start the debugging session in Idea
5. Enjoy

More information: [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)